# Who are the space artists behind these images of the Boeing X-20 Dyna-Soar?

Tags: space-art

According to [this interesting item](http://www.collectorsweekly.com/stories/181391-rare-vintage-boeing-x-20-dyna-soar-usaf), the artist of this auction-found poster is Robert McCall.

[image]

But who are the space artists who produced these two images of the [Boeing X-20 Dyna-Soar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-20_Dyna-Soar)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't found the best way to credit these images yet, hoping the answer will help in that. They can both be found widely using reverse image lookup with a search engine.

Comment: I hope that guy on the phone is calling his family to say goodbye because he's about to get killed by the blast.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ya, seems to a bit of artistic license there. I'm enjoying the shape of the fins on the middle one - could it be something innovative there?

Comment: I'm assuming that's how the fins were really planned based on this:

http://www.boeingimages.com/Docs/BOE/Media/TR3_WATERMARKED/1/a/8/0/BI44537.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First image is apparently by Robert McCall

http://www.collectorsweekly.com/stories/181391-rare-vintage-boeing-x-20-dyna-soar-usaf

Second is Frederick E Fahdt (also, better image quality)

https://2ch.hk/spc/src/242910/14514290041960.png

I've got nothing on the third one.

Comment: The better image quality on the Frederick E Fahdt work helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: okay, 2 out of 3 ain't bad!