# Why are fins located on stage 2 of Iranian rocket Zol Janah?

Tags: launch-vehicle, aerodynamics, fins, iran

Iranian launch vehicle Zol-Janah has fin like structure on the second stage of the vehicle. Does aerodynamic characteristics of vehicle improve with fins near the centre of mass? Also will the fins cause delta-v penalty when added to second stage?

Info: Zol-Janah is a 3 stage, 220kg to LEO capable launch vehicle.

[Youtube video of the Zol-Janah suborbital launch](https://youtu.be/7FFSXF8CNr8)

Comment: It looks like they bolted a SRM to the bottom of an existing missile.

Comment: other questions about things with fins or wings: [ISRO's space plane on top of of a rocket - how unstable was it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20739/12102) and [Are the US shuttle and Buran the only space planes to have launched vertically with wings exposed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20727/12102)